# Reversi (Othello) Java simple program returns wrong moves

Tags: java, reversi

I've been trying to implement simple program that returns valid move of Reversi / Othello game.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work and I cannot really see why. It returns [2,2] which is certainly not valid move.

`//myColor, opponentColor, Reversi move etc. are already defined.`

I would be glad if you pointed out flaw in my system.

```
@Override
public ReversiMove makeNextMove(int[][] board) {

    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            if (board[y][x] != myColor && board[y][x] != opponentColor) {
                int nextX = x + 1;

                while (nextX < 7 && board[y][nextX] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[y][nextX + 1] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextX++;
                }

                nextX = x - 1;

                while (nextX > 0 && board[y][nextX] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[y][nextX - 1] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextX--;
                }

                int nextY = y + 1;

                while (nextY < 7 && board[nextY][x] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[nextY + 1][x] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextY++;
                }

                nextY = y - 1;

                while (nextY > 0 && board[nextY][x] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[nextY - 1][x] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextY--;
                }

                nextX = x + 1;
                nextY = y + 1;

                while (nextX < 7 && nextY < 7 && board[nextY][nextX] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[nextY + 1][nextX + 1] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextX++;
                    nextY++;
                }

                nextX = x - 1;
                nextY = y - 1;

                while (nextX > 0 && nextY > 0 && board[nextY][nextX] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[nextY - 1][nextX - 1] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextX--;
                    nextY--;
                }

                nextX = x + 1;
                nextY = y - 1;

                while (nextX < 7 && nextY > 0 && board[nextY][nextX] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[nextY - 1][nextX + 1] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextX++;
                    nextY--;
                }

                nextX = x - 1;
                nextY = y + 1;

                while (nextX > 0 && nextY < 7 && board[nextY][nextX] == this.opponentColor) {
                    if (board[nextY + 1][nextX - 1] == this.myColor) {
                        return new ReversiMove(y,x);
                    }
                    nextX--;
                    nextY++;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return new ReversiMove(-1, -1);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

board[x][y] structure...

sometime refer as:

board[y][nextX] instead of board[nextX][y]

Comment: Edited: now there should be everywhere board [x][y] format

Comment: Does it returns [2,2] every time ?

Comment: Can you provide the content of ReversiMove(...)

Comment: it is part of school project and it cannot be viewed by me:( but I think return values are perfectly okay, there has to be mistake in NextY and NextX logic (or the >0 and <7)...

it always fails on the first turn where it returns 2,2

"Wrong move by myPlayer :Move{x=2, y=2}
Player 1 result: 
Dummy Player WON > Score:2, Stones:4
Player2 result: 
myPlayer ERROR > Score:0, Stones:0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
".
.
note: Dummy is created by the teacher and I cannot see his code.